# Regressor vs. AR/MA terms

Tags: multiple-regression, autoregressive

I'm running a regression to model Hong Kong's office rentals series:

Source:[Private Office - Average Rents by Grade by District (from 1982)](http://www.rvd.gov.hk/doc/en/statistics/his_data_8.xls)

Source:[All HK Property Market Statistics](http://www.rvd.gov.hk/en/property_market_statistics/index.html)

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.06999    0.02690   2.602  0.01068 *  
D4_UNem     -12.18370    1.72799  -7.051 2.34e-10 ***
GDPr_chg     -1.61744    0.52219  -3.097  0.00253 ** 
Inflation     1.38991    0.28273   4.916 3.47e-06 ***
> vif(m3)
   D4_UNem  GDPr_chg Inflation 
  2.200651  2.191869  1.010960
```

Simply from regression, these 3 variables are significant; However its ACF and PACF shows significant auto-correlation among the residuals:

[image]

However, whenever I add any AR/MA ERROR terms, they make these regressors insignificant. (except AR1, but AR1 is not sufficient to remove all the auto-correlations.

What would you guys do? Does it mean my regressors really shouldn't be included? Thanks everyone!

Plots of the Variables:
[image]

Original Y-series & Converted Y series:[image]

[**********Link to the raw data*********](https://www.dropbox.com/s/39jj82u00tu1qj7/Data%20for%20Office%20Rental.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: You might want to try an internet search for 'spurious regression'

Comment: From   Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

Dickey-Fuller = -3.7966, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.02173
alternative hypothesis: stationary';       So the series are stationary right?

Comment: 1) I doubt the series is actually stationary. Can you plot it?  2) the problem of spurious regression can actually occur even with stationary series.

Comment: 1) What are the values in the plot? Has the y-series been smoothed?

Comment: y-series is the Last plot, Office_rent_chg, it is simply the year-on-year % change of the office price index; no smoothing at all. Have added the original series in the post as well. Thanks again @Glen_b

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer now. Do you have a source for the data? Okay -- (1) ADF tests for a unit root against an alternative of no unit root. Not all nonstationarity is of that form (and I don't think if there's nonstationarity in an index that it would be of that form).  My guess just from looking would be that it's probably not actually stationary, but as mentioned before ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... its possible to have spurious regression relationships [even when you do have stationarity](http://www.alco.lu/docs/events/Paper_Agiakloglou_08_04_2010.pdf); a good degree of care is required (that paper prewhitens, which is what I was taught to do long ago). (2) While it's quite possible there is nothing left above an ARMA model for the transformed $y$, my original instinct would have been to consider a model with some lags in x's, at least for some of those variables.  Renting offices has some degree of inertia, so I'd expect some of those x's could easily lag a quarter or so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the enlightening comments! (a) The link for the data source is now at the bottom of the post. (b) You are correct, using unit root test for both of the series, both of them do not reject the H0 of ADF tests. Indeed they are not stationary even though I have converted it to % change. And I found first difference can solve the problem.   (c) Is it a common practice for statisticians to do ADF tests for ALL the series (or just the dependent series?) before constructing any time series regressions?  @Glen_b

Comment: I wouldn't hazard a guess as to what the most common practices among statisticians are. (I wouldn't generally bother with formal tests myself, since they tend to answer the wrong question; the question isn't so much 'can we reject this H0?' or 'will we fail to reject that one?' -- given enough data, you're very likely to conclude you have at least some form of nonstationarity -- it's questions like 'how much impact does it have?', and 'presuming there's some nonstationarity, what's a reasonable way to deal with it?')

Comment: When I asked for a source, I wasn't so much seeking the data as the details (in reference form) of where the data originated. When you first wrote your post, you wrote of it as if it was a well known series; I edited that to say something different, but I'm not happy with that change and it would be better to have an explicit reference to the source if there is one.

Comment: It is actually from Rating and Valuation Department of Hong Kong - "Private Office - Rental Indices by Grade (from 1978)" [link](http://www.rvd.gov.hk/doc/en/statistics/his_data_8.xls) Thanks again. @Glen_b

Comment: [All Official Indices of Hong Kong Property Market](http://www.rvd.gov.hk/en/property_market_statistics/index.html)